# Is it possible to rename a file on FTP server programmatically using cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ftp

My basic requirement is to add a ".temp" suffix to a file while it is getting uploaded on to the FTP server (suffix should be only for time until the file is fully uploaded).

As per my understanding, i thought this could be achieved by: Add a suffix to file on the local machine, then upload it and after the upload is complete, rename the file to remove suffix on server.

But now the another problem is that i could not found a way to rename a file on FTP server using cocoa. I know renaming a file is feasible using Java or other languages but i want to achieve the same in objectiveC.

Please tell be if the above task is feasible and if it is what is the approach i should follow?

FYI: I know how to upload and download a file on FTP server using NSInputStream and NSOutputStream.

Thanks. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CFNetwork FTP docs. They do not mention exactly your case, but there may be a way to sent RNFR and RNTO commands over the stream.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFFTPTasks/CFFTPTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH9-SW1

There is also a sample project you can look into:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_SimpleFTPSample_txt.html

This library claims to do what you want (rename remote files)
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ftp-objc.asp

Comment: Thanks. I have already checked these, but couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check the link to the library I've added.